# what is the difference between dsd and dlm="," in SAS?

Tags: sas

Let me sum up what I have got from this website. https://communities.sas.com/t5/General-SAS-Programming/Please-explain-DSD-and-DLM-differences/td-p/146773

(1): Without dsd, the cursor passes all the delimiters before reading the next field, while on the other hand, with dsd, the cursor only pass one delimiter.

(2): If you use dsd, the informat should use a colon somehow?

Do you know any differences between the two? Many thanks for your time and attention.

Comment: How does DLM vs DSD treat consecutive spaces? How does DLM vs DSD treat quoted character fields?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious difference is how `DSD` treats consecutive delimiters.  From the [docs](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm#a000853530):

> When you specify `DSD`, SAS **treats two consecutive delimiters as a
>   missing value** and **removes quotation marks from character values**.

Whereas the default functionality of `DLM=','` is to treat consecutive commas as a single comma, `DSD` will assign missing values between consecutive commas.  Here's an example:

```
data work.dlm_test;
    infile datalines dlm=',';  /* using dlm */
    input var1 var2 var3;
    datalines; /* note how the consecutive commas are treated! */
1,2,3
1,,3
,2,3
;

data work.dsd_test;
    infile datalines dsd; /* using dsd */
    input var1 var2 var3;
    datalines;
1,2,3
1,,3
,2,3
;

proc print data=dlm_test;
    /* this will print something like:
    OBS | var1 | var2 | var3
   -----+------+------+------   Note only 2 observations b/c of 
     1  |  1   |  2   | 3       default FLOWOVER functionality.
     2  |  1   |  3   | 2  <--- Also, final '3' is ignored because there
                                is no variable to store it.
    */
run;

proc print data=dsd_test;
    /* this will print something like:
    OBS | var1 | var2 | var3
   -----+------+------+------
     1  |  1   |  2   | 3
     2  |  1   |  .   | 3  <-- note the missing value in var2
     3  |  .   |  2   | 3  <-- note the third observation, with missing val
    */
run;
```

Also, `DSD` will be able to tell that a comma found inside quotation marks is actually not a delimiter, but part of a character string.  In contrast, if you use only `DLM=','`, then it will ignore quotation marks and treat every comma-cluster as a delimiter.

*TIP:* By default, `DSD` drops the quotes around character strings, but you can keep the quotes by using the `~`format identifier in the `INPUT` statement.

It is useful to note that `DSD` and `DLM` can also be used together to get the behavior of `DSD`, but change the default delmiiter from a comma to something else, like a semicolon (;).  Example:

```
    infile (filename) dsd dlm=';';
```

I found [this documentation page](https://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrdict/64316/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000146932.htm#a000165927) to be the most instructive.

**Remember:** `DSD` stands for "delimiter-sensitive data" because it is more deliberate about processing delimiters!

Answer (score 0):

The real issue how the input statement behaves when it sees a delimiter when it starts to read a variable. With the `DSD` option it will set the value to missing and move the pointer past the delimiter.  Without the DSD option it will skip over the delimiter (or multiple adjacent delimiters) before reading the value.  You can confirm this by reading a line that starts with a delimiter.

The colon modifier helps when the actual value is shorter than the informat's width, but it also helps by moving the pointer PAST the delimiter so that the NEXT variable is read correctly.  This is what makes it important when using formatted input statements with the `DSD` infile option.

You can avoid the need to worry about the : modifiers by using an `INFORMAT` statement instead of listing the informats in the input statement.